# What's a Pythonic way of parsing a JSON payload which may be none?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
    payload = event.get('body', '')
    parsed_payload = json.loads(payload)
    username = parsed_payload.get('username')
    password = parsed_payload.get('password')
    print(username)
    print(password)
```

Which works fine until `'body': null` which causes the following error, presumably because the value of body is null so event.get('body', '') means the default isn't used, just `null`.

> [ERROR] TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray,
> not NoneType

I tried the following:

```
    payload = event.get('body')
    if payload:
        parsed_payload = json.loads(payload)
        username = parsed_payload.get('username')
        password = parsed_payload.get('password')
    if username and password:
        print(username)
        print(password)
```

Now I get a new error:

```
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'username' where it is not associated with a value
```

At which point I could either have already assigned username and password with a none or I could have another if statement but it seems unpythonic.

Could someone point me in the direction of best practice here please?

Comment: `if payload is not None:` is the Pythonic way to check if a thing is `None`.
See [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)

Comment: Please update your question with the full error tracebacks.

Comment: Move the second `if` inside the first?

Comment: Or if the `username` and `password` fields can’t be missing when `body` is non-null, just delete the `if username and password:` line without changing any indentation.

Comment: are you sure you want `event.get('body', '')` and not just `event['body']`... I often see people using `get` with dicts because they think it's "safer" but then not handling the case of the defaulted value properly, and often the key is not really optional anyway either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
payload = event.get('body') or '{}'
```